# Functional/Acceptance test of server code in iOS with UI Automation

Tags: ios, sockets, functional-testing, acceptance-testing

So I am working on a project where my iOS application acts as a server and receives connections from clients that send location data.  My application reads this data from a socket and either updates the location of the clients on a MKMapView or creates a new one if it is a new connection.

I have my code completely unit tested so I feel some what confident about it.  However, I am trying to write an acceptance test that will start my app and have a client connect to the socket, send some data and see if my app adds an MKAnnotation to the map view.  Now I have had a little bit of experience with UI Automation but my issue is how can I write this networking code.

Here is what I need the test to do:

1.) Go to view controller where this networking code is happening (Easy enough with UI Automation)

2.) Once the view controller is loaded the server will start on port 2500 (Easy enough)

3.) Have a client connect to the server and send a message (This is what I don't know how to accomplish)

4.) Assert that the MKMapView has an annotation with the information I sent (Easy with UI Automation)

I know there is nothing native to javascript that will allow me to work directly with sockets, but could I use a library that uses web sockets?   Other than that option I have not been able to find any resources online to solve testing a problem like this.  I am open to any suggestions since I really don't know how to tackle this problem.  I am sure there must be some way to test this.  Thank you in advance and I am eagerly awaiting any suggetions!!